# Как использовать delegate в данном примере?

Tags: xcode, swift

Мне нужно поработать с анимацией и вот есть у меня такая функция которая вращает `view`

```
func rotate360Degrees(uiView : UIView , duration: CFTimeInterval = 2.0, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2)
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration

    if let delegate: CAAnimationDelegate = completionDelegate as! CAAnimationDelegate? {
        rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
    }

    uiView.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Но я новичок и не совсем пойму как тут можно использовать `completionDelegate` ?

Я так понял мы применяем  delegate когда нам нужно получить доступ к методам какого то класса. Тогда нужно унаследоваться от класса и сделать `delegate`

Но в данном примере я не совсем пойму с какой целью можно использовать эту возможность?

Comment: что то не совсем понятно, что вы спрашиваете. в вашем примере программа определяет присутствует ли competionDelegate и назначете тот же класс rotateAnimation.delegate

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko вот у меня есть параметр `completionDelegate` который я могу передать , а могу не передавать. Если я его не передаю то метод берет его default значение nil и естественно проверка `if let delegate: CAAnimationDelegate` не проходит. Мой вопрос в том, что я так понимаю, что `completionDelegate` нужно передать переменную типа `CAAnimationDelegate` что прошла проверка, но я не совсем понимаю что будет если передать `CAAnimationDelegate` ? зачем может понадобиться это делать?